# Certificates List is empty in WebRole

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, certificate-store

I am writing a code in my web app which needs to list and search for a specific Certificate installed on web role.
Here is my code

```
// using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

var store = new X509Store() ;
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
LoggingService.Info(String.Format(
     "{0} Certificate(s) are found in store",store.Certificates.Count));
for(int index=0;index<store.Certificates.Count;index++)
{
    LoggingService.Info(String.Format(
        "Subject:{0}, Thumbprint:{1}",store.Certificates[index].Subject,
        store.Certificates[index].Thumbprint));
}
_Certificate = store.Certificates.Find(
     X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, this.CertificateThumbprint, false)[0];
```

Now Problem is, even though a certificate is added in the web role through portal and also present in the config file. store.Certificates.Count is zero. This code runs perfectly in emulator but somehow is unable to list the web role certificates. How can I access the certificate installed on web role?

Comment: Is the certificate store correct?  Any errors (like a permission problem)?

Comment: Yes certificate store is correct.Also logged in my web role and it is weird that there is no certificate in Personal store. But I can see the certificate in IIS on web role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, I was not providing any store name and location in Store class and was assuming it will search in every store and location but it was not like this. I then provided the Store name and location and now system is able to find certificate.